# bootstrap-select dropdown making it work on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, bootstrap-select

I am having really hard time with this. Can someone please help?

I want to have native dropdown kick in for Mobile Devices

1. http://jsfiddle.net/4UjVr/4/
2. Docs: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#mobile

```js
$(function() {
  $('#desktop').selectpicker({
    container: 'body'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/120557/Expires/12-2014/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select id="desktop" data-live-search="true">
  <option>cow</option>
  <option>bull</option>
  <option>cow</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Tes3</option>
  <option>Tes4</option>

  <option class="get-class" disabled>ox</option>
  <optgroup label="test" data-subtext="another test" data-icon="icon-ok">
    <option>ASD</option>
    <option>Bla</option>
    <option>Ble</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to have native dropdown kick in for Mobile Devices

Answer (score 12):

This seems to do the trick.

```js
$(function () {
$('#desktop').selectpicker({
    container: 'body'   
});

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('#desktop').selectpicker('mobile');
}
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/120557/Expires/12-2014/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select id="desktop" data-live-search="true">
  <option>cow</option>
  <option>bull</option>
  <option>cow</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Tes3</option>
  <option>Tes4</option>

  <option class="get-class" disabled>ox</option>
  <optgroup label="test" data-subtext="another test" data-icon="icon-ok">
    <option>ASD</option>
    <option>Bla</option>
    <option>Ble</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into this with the current version (1.10.0 as of today), using the `mobile: true` default option does not work as expected.  I found that the above comment by @Chirag resolves this.

Answer (score 2):

If you guys are wondering what is going on here is what is actually needed.

```
<script>
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('mobile');
            }
            else {
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
            }
</script>
```

and in the html

```
<select class="selectpicker mobile-device"></select>
```

**EDITED**

At the very bottom I added this scrip if it is a webpage I added some code to prevent some weird click events on drop downs. Because the mobile css class needs to be remove for better appearance.

```
<script>
                if (!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
                    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-device'); 
                    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
                    {
                        elements[i].classList.remove('mobile-device');
                    }
                }      
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here from Google, it is worth noting that the `mobile-device` class is automatically added to the `<select>` when the mobile option is enabled.

> This class makes the select the same width and height as the button,
> places the select above the button (via z-index), and then hides it by
> setting the opacity to 0. So, it looks like a button, but when you
> click on it, you're actually clicking on the select, thus opening the
> native select menu.

~ Direct quote from a [Comment on an Issue on Github](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1297#issuecomment-185307122)

Because the plugin is only adding CSS to make the select rise to the top to make it trigger the native dropdown, then any custom CSS you may have added could be overriding that of the plugin, such as a higher `z-index` on another element, as it was in my case.

Removing any custom CSS will solve further issues of the native dropdown not appearing.